Upgrading D3.js within Sencha ExtJS
We are currently licensed for Ext JS Premium.
Ext JS Premium 7.4.0.42 was released on May 6, 2021.
I need some cool stuff from
https://github.com/d3/d3-interpolate/blob/main/README.md
I noticed in one of the D3 files the following note:
 - npm install d3
 - (in the d3 package directory)
 `rollup -c -f iife -i index.js -n d3 -output=d3.js`

Do I need to do this in order to get some of the neato stuff from modern D3 into ExtJS?

There is a D3-interpolate npm repo also:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/d3-interpolate
use
npm install d3
npm install d3-interpolate

